# Getting an unknown IP Address from known MAC address using ARP?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping, mac-address, arp

I am on a Windows platform (Win7) and I have a scenario where I know the MAC addresses of devices but their IPs are dynamically chosen when booting up.

I want to write a batch script that pings these specific devices to make sure they are alive. There are many other devices on the network that I don't want to ping, just a set of 10 specific MACs I want to get the IP address from then ping them only. They are all in the address scheme 10.1.(1-255).(1-255)

This much I know, I can ping the entire address spectrum and then

```
arp -a > arp.txt
```

...to output a document containing the list of IPs and associated MAC addresses in this format

```
Interface: 192.168.2.27 --- 0xb
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.2.1           00-1f-90-c0-25-fd     dynamic   
  192.168.2.3           00-00-aa-a1-d3-78     dynamic   
  192.168.2.16          ac-72-89-a7-7e-98     dynamic   
  192.168.2.17          78-45-c4-2f-71-0b     dynamic   
  192.168.2.18          68-b5-99-8e-1c-35     dynamic   
  192.168.2.24          b8-ac-6f-30-00-34     dynamic   
  192.168.2.26          00-90-a9-6f-e0-be     dynamic
```

**My question is** how can I (via a batch script or other automated method) find the line of the MAC address I am interested in and put the IP address into a variable that I can then use.

In UNIX I can grep but in Windows I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Install Cygwin and do it the Unix way that you already know?

Comment: findstr may work for you...?

Comment: @rpax, `type` is the equivalent of `cat`, `find` and `findstr` are the equivalents of `grep`.

Comment: @druciferre thank you! I mistook a command with the other

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I can't really modify the system I'm working on in that fashion. I can run a portable exe file if need be but installing Cygwin isn't possible unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output to `find` and use a `for` loop.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('arp -a ^| find "00-1f-90-c0-25-fd"') do (
    set ip=%%i
    set mac=%%j
)
```

You could alter this a bit to make a batch script that will ping by entering the MAC address like so `pingbymac.bat 00-1f-90-c0-25-fd`

```
@for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('arp -a ^| find "%~1"') do (
    ping %%i 
)
```

Comment: You can use `%~1` which will remove any surrounding quotes, if they exist, otherwise it will act the same as `%1`.  Off topic, but this allows a construct like `"%~1"` to be used in any comparison and will handle quoted or unquoted terms and always return a quoted term.

Answer (score 1):

to find the line:

```
arp -a |find "78-45-c4-2f-71-0b"
```

To find the IP-Address only:

```
for /f %i in ('arp -a ^|find "2c-27-d7-ef-f8-77"') do echo %i
```

(write `%%i` instead of `%i` if using it in a batchfile)